# How to make a custom collection or grouping folders in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filesystems, directory-listing

I use windows 8.1. I have 10 folders in my root folder of a drive, namely `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3`, `folder4`, `folder5`, `folder6`, `folder7`, `folder8`, `folder9` and `folder10`. I want to group these folders into custom group. When I pick one group, I want to see all the folders in that specific group alone, so that I can easily pick my  folders.

For example, say I have a group `alpha` and I want to include `folder1` and `folder2` in `alpha`. Then `folder3`, `folder4` and `folder5` in `beta`, and rest of the folders in `gamma`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by adding comments to a folder, adding the `Comments` column to a `Details` view, and then grouping on `Comments`.

[image]

A comment is added to a folder via a `desktop.ini` file with the following contents:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
InfoTip=Gamma
```

The comment can be any text, including spaces, and is terminated by the newline character in th `.ini` file. No quotes are required.

The folder must have its `Rad-only` attribute set for its `desktop.ini` file to be processed. This can be done via **PolwerShell** opened to the folder path:

```
(gi .).Attributes = (gi .).Attributes -bor 0x04
```

I've put the **PowerShell** code to add a comment to a folder into a couple of context menu entries in this `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\Shell\Add comment to folder]
@=""
"Position"="Bottom"
"SeparatorBefore"=""
"SeparatorAfter"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\Shell\Add comment to folder\Command]
@="powershell  -Command \"& {sl '%V';$f='desktop.ini';$Txt = Try{(gc $f -raw -ea stop) -replace '(?s)\\s*\\[\\.\\w+]\\s',''}Catch{};([Regex]::UnEscape('[.ShellClassInfo]\\nInfoTip={0}\\n')+$Txt) -f (Read-Host Comment) | sc $f -force;(gi .).Attributes = (gi .).Attributes -bor 1;(gi $f).Attributes = (gi $f).Attributes -bor 4}\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\Add comment to folder]
@=""
"Position"="Bottom"
"SeparatorBefore"=""
"SeparatorAfter"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\Add comment to folder\Command]
@="powershell -Command \"& {sl '%V';$f='desktop.ini';$Txt = Try{(gc $f -raw -ea stop) -replace '(?s)\\s*\\[\\.\\w+]\\s',''}Catch{};([Regex]::UnEscape('[.ShellClassInfo]\\nInfoTip={0}\\n')+$Txt) -f (Read-Host Comment) | sc $f -force;(gi .).Attributes = (gi .).Attributes -bor 1;(gi $f).Attributes = (gi $f).Attributes -bor 4}\""
```

Save the above as a `.reg` file, select the file in **File Explorer**, right-click and select `Merge`. Accept all prompts.

When you launch the command, a **PowerShell** console window will appear, prompting for your commennt text. Type your text and press `Enter`.

[image]

You also filter the view using the droplist from the `Comments` header:

[image]