# Manually change a folder's meta data

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

In the Windows File Explorer I can select some 320 different columns<sup>1</sup> to display for various files and folders, see the screenshot below. I'd like to be able to manually manipulate the contents of some fields, to be able to sort my *folders* e.g. on "Business Region". How can I edit the meta data of my folders to utilise these various possible column entries for the file explorer? For example adding a state/province in the "Business Region" column.

NB: We use both Windows 10 and Windows 11.

[image]

<sup>1</sup> See [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64601307/5211833) for a more-or-less complete list.

Comment: Does my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1694843/881098) help? I've also managed to add the `★★★★★` "Rating" column for folders as well, though that requires Admin permissions to modify the HKLM hive of the registry.

Comment: Screenshot: https://imgur.com/UhhvJWZ

Comment: @KeithMiller looks very relevant and handy, thanks! It does look, however, to be able to set only one "comment" column; is it possible to set more than one? That way we would be able to have several sorting categories in place. Using either manually named/created columns (e.g. "region", "car" etc), or 'misusing' one of the default columns is both fine by me.

Answer (score 4):

If you add the `Comments` column to a `Details` view of `This PC` or the UserProfile folder, you'll see descriptions of the folders' purpose for the Music, Pictrues, and Videos folders. Those are added to the folders via their respective desktop.ini files. Specifically, a value named `InfoTip` in the `[.ShellClassInfo]` section. The data can be either a resource reference as seen in the system folders:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21790
InfoTip=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-12689
...
```

or a string literal:

```
LocalizedResourceName=Custom Display Name
InfoTip=Custom Comment
...
```

---

### Edit: Updated info -- Two ways to "hijack" other properties

There are two ways to make use of properties that already exist within the Windows Property System, but that aren't normally properties of folders.

The first which I just recently discovered, has the advantage of being totally contained within the folder's dessktop,ini file, and thus is accesible to a standard user with no need for admin access. The second requires at least one-time admin access for editing the HKLM registry hive to establish mapping between the property and a custom .ini file value.

The easier method though, is limited to the properties found in the [FMTID_SummaryInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/stg/the-summary-information-property-set) property set:

| Name | Type | PID | VT code | VT name | Canonical Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Title | String | 2 | 31 | VT_LPWSTR | System.Title |
| Subject | String | 3 | 31 | VT_LPWSTR | System.Subject |
| Authors | Multi-string | 4 | 31 | VT_LPWSTR | System.Author |
| Tags | Multi-string | 5 | 31 | VT_LPWSTR | System.Keywords |
| Total editing time | TimeSpan(ish) | 10 | 21 | VT_UI8 | System.Document.TotalEditingTime |
| Last Printed | FileTime | 11 | 64 | VT_FILETIME | System.Document.DatePrinted |
| Content Created | FileTime | 12 | 64 | VT_FILETIME | System.Document.DateCreated |
| Date last saved | FileTime | 12 | 64 | VT_FILETIME | System.Document.DateSaved |
| Pages | Int32 | 14 | 3 | VT_I4 | System.Document.PageCount |
| Word count | Int32 | 14 | 3 | VT_I4 | System.Document.WordCount |
| Program Name | String | 18 | 31 | VT_LPWSTR | System.ApplicationName |

- In an **Explorrer** Details view, the `Content created` and `Date last saved` columns are normally populated by "mirroring" the file system properties `Date created` and `Date modifed` respectively. Setting these values via the `desktop.ini` file will override this default behavior without affecting the file system properties.

In the `desktop.ini` file, they are assigned using the format:

- `Prop<PID> = <VT code>,<Property value>`

```
[{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}]
Prop2  = 31,Title
Prop3  = 31,Subject 
Prop4  = 31,Author1;Author2
Prop5  = 31,Tags;Tag1;Tag2
; Total editning time is essentially an unsighed TimeSpan,
; entered as a uint64 value representing the ticks in the TimeSpan
Prop10 = 21,90000000000
; Last Printed
Prop11 = 64,1969-07-20T20:17:00
; Content Created
Prop12 = 64,2023-04-20T11:11:11
; Date last saved
Prop13 = 64,1944-06-06T06:30:00
; Pages
Prop14 = 3,942
; Word count
Prop15 = 3,999
Prop18 = 31,Application Name
```

---

*** End of update edit ***

---

To assign other properties, such as `Rating`, the other piece to the puzzle is the mapping the InfoTip value to the Property System. This is specified in the regsitry, under the key:

```
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DesktopIniPropertyMap\PropertySetStorage
```

[image: Screenshot of Regsitry]

Every available property can be refeneced by a unique [PropertyKey](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/) which consists of an FMTID/PID pair. The FMTID is the [Format Identifier (FMTID)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/stg/format-identifiers), a group of related properties, and the PID is an integer that references a particular property within the FMTID group.

The FMTID/PID for System.Comments is:
`{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9},6`
These values name the subkeys that map that property to  the entries found under the PID key:

| Name | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Key | REG_SZ | Value name |
| Section | REG_SZ | Section Name |
| VarType | REG_DWORD | Data Type |

- `VarType` specifies a value from the [VARENUM enumeration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtypes/ne-wtypes-varenum)

[image]

So, following the example InfoTip gives us, we cah "hijack" other properties as well.

While you can find some FMTID/PID listings online, I use NirSoft's [Propety System Viewer](https://www.google.com/url?client=internal-element-cse&cx=partner-pub-5286073190998405:5399172980&q=https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/windows_property_system_view.html&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwji1JuF35L3AhUahIkEHStzAlwQFnoECAkQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2cbLL9q-rwoosapkxcDww2) --- it's a great tool.

So, if you wanted to populate The `Country/Region` property for folders, you create the registry key:
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DesktopIniPropertyMap\PropertySetStorage\{B0B87314-FCF6-4FEB-8DFF-A50DA6AF561C}\100`
and specify the Key, Section, and VarType for the desktop.ini file.

[image]

So with the mapping added to the registry, a folder with a desktop.ini file specifying:

```
[Custom]
Rating=50
Region=Midwest
[.ShellClassInfo]
InfoTip=and now...
```

and relavent columns added to a `Details` view, we get:

[image]

Remember:

A folder has to have its `ReadOnly` atttrube set for the `desktop.ini` file to be processed. Add the `Attributes` column to a Details view in Explorer to check the attributes for folders. Ignore the Read-Only checkbox in the Properties dialog, it's not a status indicator.

A quick way to create a basic desktop.ini file and set the folder's ReadOnly attribute at the same time is to assign a custom icon to the folder via the Customize tab in the folder's Properties dialog. You can then edit the desktop.ini file -- adding your custom entries and even delete the custom icon info if you didn't really want it.

---

Reg export for `Country/Region`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DesktopIniPropertyMap\PropertySetStorage\{B0B87314-FCF6-4FEB-8DFF-A50DA6AF561C}\100]
"Key"="Region"
"Section"="Custom"
"VarType"=dword:0000001f
```

Reg export for `Rating` (note that `VarType` now specifies `VT_UINT`, an unsigned integer):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DesktopIniPropertyMap\PropertySetStorage\{64440492-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03}\9]
"Key"="Rating"
"Section"="Custom"
"VarType"=dword:00000017
```

Comment: Very interesting but I search to add "Status" (or "Task Status")  AND "Comment" columns to folder's view ! How can I do ? Can you add this case in your answer ?

Comment: `Comment` is already functional, all you need to do is add the `"InfoTip"=Comment Text` data to the `[.ShellClassInfo]` section of the folder's `desktop.ini` file. That's describeed in the answer already. Will take a look at `Status` when I get a chance...

Comment: I have done all your example and also added "Status" = {000214A1-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\9] but all these columns are empty. Are you sure that what you written in 2014 continue to work now in 2022 on Windows 10.

Comment: Just for information, my langage on Windows 10 is French.

Comment: The date of my answer is April 14 of *this year*! :D That comment really threw me off! LOL

Comment: `{000214A1-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\9` is the property ID for `System.Status`, and **PropertySystemExplorer** reveals that property is not viewable. I think you want `System.Communication.TaskStatus`: `{BE1A72C6-9A1D-46B7-AFE7-AFAF8CEF4999},100`. It's a 2-byte unsigned integer with enumeration values of: `Not Started (0), In Progress (1), Complete (2), Waiting (3), Deferred (4)`. Like `Region`, it's stored as VT_UINT, so your registry mapping would have a `VarType` of 23 (0x17).

Comment: Meant to say `...like Rating...`, not `...like Region...`

Comment: @schlebe: I just posted an answer to another question that includes code to create context menu entries to easily set these custom properties. You might want to run it and examine the registry entries and files it creates. `Task Status` is similar to `Rating` and could be added in the same way. https://superuser.com/a/1741597/881098

Comment: Thanks for all these informations. For year, I speak french and day is alway before month in contrary of english language ! Ok now, I know that your solution is actual and that it must work on my PC.

Comment: I have found my mistake. So that all what you write work, I must execute `attrib +r foldername` on all folders containing a `desktop.ini` file as explained in following question
https://superuser.com/questions/1117824/how-to-get-windows-to-read-copied-desktop-ini-file
All is working 'region','task status' and 'rating'

Comment: The need for the folder's `ReadOnly` attribute to be set is mentioned in my answer as well. If you open a **PowerShell** window to the folder in question, you can use: `(gi .).Attributes += 'ReadOnly'`.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. But that is why I encountered a problem ! I read again what you written and I find that your explanation about READ-ONLY attribute for folder is a little confuse. Perhaps can you insist on this part (= folder attribute must be READ-ONLY). This is only an advice. Thanks for your help.