# Give Windows 10 music metadata to non-audio files/directories

Tags: windows-10, audio, pdf, mp3, metadata

I currently have a large directory with a ton of subdirectories, each one has an MIDI file, PDF (sheet music), and MP3.

I'd like to add metadata to these files (such as artist name, song title, album, year) but it seems these options are only available on the MP3 files.

Is there any way to add this metadata to directories/folders, PDF, and MIDI files?

[image: Folders with no metadata]

[image: Files with no metadata]

Comment: The short answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change some of metadata of folders if you follow this detailed answer: https://superuser.com/a/1716276/1145698 E.g. title is changed here:

[image: Changed title]

However, for files I don't think you can do much as a user, at least without any 3rd party solutions.

The way it works is that Windows has an API for reading metadata from files with various extensions and Windows is able to handle some of the formats by itself by default, e.g. it can read ID3 of `.mp3` files or Exif data of various formats. Apps can add additional code, so called property handlers, to handle custom formats. You can read more about them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/building-property-handlers-properties).

What I would recommend to organize things nicely is to use a file manager that supports tagging, e.g. [Files](https://files.community/). Or anything similar. You'll be able to achieve what you need much more efficiently with 3rd party apps than if you played around with Windows Explorer.